# Correctly flat elements of a numpy array in python

Tags: python, flatten

I have the following exemplary list of elements (2,2,2,3).
It is composed by two elements of 2x2x3 features:

```
X = np.array([[[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], 
               [[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]],
              
              [[[12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]], 
               [[18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23]]],             
            ])
```

Now I want to obtain the new list of two elements with flatten features (2,12):

```
Y = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],  
              [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],           
            ])
```

How I can obtain Y from X?

I tried:

```
np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0],X.shape[1]*X.shape[2]*X.shape[3]))
```

But obtained Y = X.

Which is the correct general instruction to use?
Thank you very much!

Comment: `Y = np.reshape(X, (X.shape[0],X.shape[1]*X.shape[2]*X.shape[3]))`, is working for me

Comment: BTW X is a not a list is numpy array

Comment: You could also use `Y = X.reshape((2, -1))` which imo is more pythonic.

Comment: OK thank you for the answers ;-) Yes, now it works!